# Why do I get a 400 error when logging a user using bcrypt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, bcrypt

I'm trying to create login authentication, but I keep getting an 400 error in Postman saying that my syntax is bad when testing things out. I'm pretty sure my entire User model is solid, but for good measure, I've attached the whole thing in case something's off there. Otherwise, I'm really not sure what the problem is or where to go from here.

This is the data that I'm sending that triggers the **400 Bad Request** (the request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax) and logs the invalid password to the console:

```
{
    "email": "andrew@example.com",
    "password": "Red12345!"
}
```

Here's my entire user model code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const validator = require('validator')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true, 
        trim: true
    }, 
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        require: true,
        trim: true, 
        lowercase: true,
        validate(value) {
            if(!validator.isEmail(value)) {
                throw new Error('Email is invalid')
            }
        }
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        validate(value) {
            if(value < 0) {
                throw new Error('Age must be a positive number.')
            }
        }
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        required: true,
        minlength: 7,
        validate(value) {
            if(value.toLowerCase().includes("password")) {
                throw new Error("Password can't be 'password'.")
            }
        }
    }
})

userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async (email, password) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email })

    if (!user) {
        throw new Error('User not found')
    }

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)

    if (!isMatch) {
        throw new Error('Invalid password')
    }

    return user
}

//Hash the plain text password before saving
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    const user = this

    if(user.isModified('password')) {
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8)
    }

    next() 
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

module.exports = User
```

And here's the user login router:

```
router.post('/users/login', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findByCredentials(req.body.email, req.body.password)
        res.send(user)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
        res.status(400).send()
    }
})
```

Comment: You've left out the two most important parts - what data you are sending and what error is being logged

Comment: Everything looks like `findByCredentials` doesn't find a match. Did you try adding `console.log` commands to the function to see what exactly is happening? Did you try adding `console.log(req.body)` to your routing function? Never assume you already know what's in variables.

Comment: Thank you for adding that. I added what I was sending and the error I was logging. I didn't log **req.body** but will do that to see what I'm getting.

Comment: @Michael so now that we know you are passing JSON data, have you included a JSON body parser with your Express config?

Comment: `isMatch` evaluates to false when I log that. `req.body` shows the right info, but when I log `user` in my router, I get an `Unhandled promise rejection` warning.

Comment: @james, no. I haven't added a body parser. I didn't think needed one at this point?

Comment: @Michael well if you are saying `req.body` has the correct values then I presume you already have one (Express doesn't handle JSON data out the box). Regardless, from what you've described it just sounds like the password for the user isn't matching up? You could try manually [verifying it](https://bcrypt.org/).

Comment: Thanks, @james. I forgot to mention that it tells me `user` in my route isn't defined, which is a problem. When I manually verify using the hashed password that I log to the console, I get that it matches.

Comment: @Michael what does `e.message` print? Presumably "Invalid password"

Comment: Can you console the user data that you are getting in the router file?              
const user = await User.findByCredentials(req.body.email, req.body.password); console.log(user);

Comment: @james Yeah, `e.message` prints invalid password.

Comment: @sunny, the logging 'user' says user isn't defined and gives me an unhandled promise rejection warning.

Comment: @Michael well that proves that the issue lies with either the hash or the password not being correct or exact. For example, does the hash come out from the DB with extra spaces? If you manually hardcode the hash into `compare` rather than using the one from the DB does the check work?

Comment: @james To be honest, I don't know how to check if the hash from the DB comes back with extra spaces, nor to I know how to hardcode the hash (I'm still learning and don't have a firm grasp on the topic). I'm following tutorials on Udemy, which are pretty thorough, but this time no such luck and others are having issues as well. I've messaged the instructor of the course, because using the code that he's written in the resources sections (the code he types on screen) gives the same errors.

Comment: @Michael `const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare('Red12345!', 'paste-hash-here')`, this will eliminate the hash being incorrect. Second thing to do is use then introduce the `password` parameter back in and then finally the `user.password` hash and check the result for each, it should help narrow the problem.

Comment: @james, still getting an error when I do it that way. I pushed my code to github, and the course creators are working on debugging it as well. I'll let you know what the solution is.

Comment: @Michael it's pretty straightforward - if you have hardcoded the credentials and it's still failing....then the credentials are wrong.

Comment: @James, yeah, but I just don't know enough to identify what, exactly, I need to fix in my code. That's where I'm struggling.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196167/discussion-between-michael-and-james).

Comment: I finally figured out the problem. In my schema, I set it up to convert all passwords to lowercase, for some reason. So I had a database full of all-lowercase passwords but hashes that might have been created from passwords that weren't all-lowercase. So that's why compare was giving me an error, even after removing the line from my schema. To fix it, I dropped my database and started over.